# Question on Index Gymnastics

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, tensor-calculus

Suppose I have a scalar quantity defined as $\Phi\equiv g^{ab}\partial_a Z\partial_b Z$.

If I have another quantity $Y_{ab}=\partial_a Z\partial_b Z$, is it possible to write $Y_{ab}$ in terms of $\Phi$?

(I am interested in writing $Y_{ab}$ as a rank (0,2) tensor in terms of $\Phi$ only, e.g. I don't want to contract $Y_{ab}$ with $g^{ab}$.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it's not possible. Your equations can also be written as

$$\Phi = \partial^a Z \partial_a Z$$

and

$$Y^a{}_b = \partial^a Z \partial_b Z,$$

so $\Phi$ is the trace of $Y^a{}_b$; you can't recover a matrix from its trace.

Comment: Thanks. I think I know the answer to this: but I suppose also that there's no creative way to manipulate a term like $\nabla_a\nabla_b\Phi$ into giving $Y_{ab}$

Comment: @Bob - $\nabla_a \nabla_b \Phi$ has a total of 4 derivatives (in $Z$) whereas $Y$ only has 2. You cannot reduce it.

Comment: @Prahar I didn't mean that form explicitly, I meant some (any) sort of creative way to tease out $Y_{ab}$ in terms of $\Phi$. (I just wrote $\nabla_a\nabla_b\Phi$ because that was the first thing that came to mind of a way to write a (0,2) tensor in terms of $\Phi$ only.) Although I agree with Javier that it won't likely work out.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to understand this as as follows. One can make an expansion of $Y_{ab}$ in terms of a complete set of matrices $\lambda^{\nu}_{ab}$
$$ Y_{ab} = \sum_{\nu} \lambda^{\nu}_{ab} \Psi^{\nu} , $$
where $\Psi^{\nu}$ are scalar coefficients. One of the elements of the set of matrices would be $g_{ab}$. So we see that your $\Phi$ is one of coefficients. Unless you know all the other coeeficients you would not be able to reproduce $Y_{ab}$.

Just to say a bit more about the set of matrices, they would have the properties:
$$ {\rm completeness}: ~~~ \sum_{\nu} \lambda^{\nu}_{ab} \lambda^{\nu}_{cd} = \delta_{ad} \delta_{cb} , $$

$$ {\rm orthogonality}: ~~~ \sum_{ab} \lambda^{\nu}_{ab} \lambda^{\mu}_{ba} = \delta^{\nu\mu} . $$